# Preprocessing each cell in range in Google Spreadsheet Formula

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to `sum` a range of values, but the values in my range comes from a formula resulting in string values (string user input, number extracted with `left()`). This makes `=sum(A:A)` not work.

What I would like to do is something along the lines of `=sum(value(A:A))`, but I need `value()` to apply to *each cell* before they are all summed up.

I would like a general solution applicable to any preprocessing formula.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
=sum(ARRAYFORMULA(--A:A))
```

BTW, you could also double minus each number before summing: `= --left(B1)` will give the number. If A:A contains text, then use `=sum(IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(--A:A)))`

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on how Arrayformula works? I'm struggling to understand the docs.